# Array of linked lists in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having difficulties on making an array of linked lists. I have this struct

```
typedef struct node {
    int id;
    struct node * next;
} t_point;

t_point* array[10];
```

and I want, for example, that array[0] points to the head of a linked list, and then fill with, repeating this process to all spaces of the array

I understand how I need to code it, but I can't get it right. I just want someone to show me and explain me the syntax.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ! Please show us what you have tried and what part causes you trouble exactly so we can help you

Comment: Try drawing what you want on paper, with boxes for the structures and arrows for the pointers.

Comment: The syntax should have been explained by your teacher/tutor. Also you will find plenty of tutorial about linked list in the web already.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Huh? Then I do it wrong for decades. I use fat dots for the pointer and the arrows for the relations;-)

Comment: Thanks, and explaining that English is not your native language, are both not necessary here (and two spelling errors where in the message about that itself ;-)  (*sorry*, *English*))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
t_point* array[10]

void link_list()
{
    int array_length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(t_point*);

    // Allocate the memory for the first list item
    array[0] = malloc(sizeof(t_point));

    // Iterate through each item in `array` and allocate it some memory
    for (int i = 1; i < array_length; i++)
    {
        // Allocate memory for the next item
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(t_point));

        // Set the previous item's `next` field to the current item pointed to by `i`
        array[i - 1]->next = array[i];
    }

    // Close the list by adding a NULL pointer
    array[array_length - 1]->next = NULL;
}
```

Also remember to `free` the `malloc`'ed memory otherwise you will get memory leaks. I'll leave that up to you.